# Limit android SimpleExoPlayerView height to control buttons

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

How to limit the height of SimpleExoPlayerView to take only the height of control buttons instead of taking all the screen height?

Here is the layout of my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:show_timeout="0"
        app:hide_on_touch="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The result is this :

[image]

And I would like something like this without having to manually set SimpleExoPlayerView height in dp:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do want I needed to do by overriding layout file exo_simple_player_view.xml and keep only the part that contains controls. I have created the layout file in res/layout/exo_simple_player_view.xml (the name must not be changed).

exo_simple_player_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <View android:id="@id/exo_controller_placeholder"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the **controller_view** Height and set it to **SimpleExoPlayerView** height

```
playerView.exo_player_control.post {
            playerView.layoutParams.height = playerView.exo_player_control.height
            podcastFragmentBinding.playerView.requestLayout()
        }
```